# Import Error: No module named pytz after using easy_install

Tags: python, python-2.7

Today is my first day at Python and have been going through problems. One that I was working on was, "Write a short program which extracts the current date and time from the operating system and prints it on screen in the following format: day, month, year, current time in GMT.
Demonstrate that it works."

I was going to use pytz, so used `easy_install pytz` 
This installed it in my site-packages (pytz-2012d-py2.7.egg)

Is this the correct directory for me to be able to import the module?

In my python shell i use from pytz import timezone I get, 
`"ImportError: No module named pytz"`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: why not use datetime modeule... http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Comment: I need it in GMT, I thought only pytz has time conversions

Comment: @avasal: As [the `datetime` documentation says](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects): "_pytz contains up-to-date information and its usage is recommended._". In other words, Python's docs recommends using `pytz` module for more advanced stuff. This is why OP needs it probably.

Comment: just doing `easy_install pytz` worked for me..

Comment: I was able to successfully do easy_install but when trying to import pytz in my shell i get no module..I am confident its because it is install it in the wrong directory. Do you know where its suppose to be installed?

Comment: @MatthewLiem: what you did is `--upgrade`,, can you try it without that

Comment: looks like all i needed to do was reset my shell window -.- thanks all for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time` module can also help here..
UTC is Coordinated Universal Time (formerly known as Greenwich Mean Time, or GMT)

```
In [18]: import time

In [19]: time.gmtime()
Out[19]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=3, tm_min=37, tm_sec=15, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=266, tm_isdst=0)

In [20]: x = time.gmtime()

In [21]: x.tm_year
Out[21]: 2012

In [22]: x.tm_mon
Out[22]: 9

In [23]: x.tm_mday
Out[23]: 22

In [24]: x.tm_hour
Out[24]: 3
```

Also can you Check the logs while you installed pytz with the below ones...

```
C:\>easy_install pytz
Searching for pytz
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pytz/
Reading http://pytz.sourceforge.net
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=79122
Reading http://www.stuartbishop.net/Software/pytz
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytz/
Best match: pytz 2012d
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pytz/pytz-2012d-py2.7.egg#md5=
e6f9219ae6eff242f13c6700413df69e
Processing pytz-2012d-py2.7.egg
Moving pytz-2012d-py2.7.egg to c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Adding pytz 2012d to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012d-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pytz
Finished processing dependencies for pytz

C:\>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> utc = pytz.utc
>>> utc.zone
'UTC'
```

Comment: +1 for giving a walkaround. However, strictly (very strictly) speaking, UTC is not GMT.

Comment: How can I get UTC timezone from time module? what i need is to convert tz-aware datetime into UTC naive. I do it by calling `tzutc = tzaware.astimezone(pytz.utc)` and then `tzutc.replace(tzinfo=None)`. Is there a better way? Most notable I'd like to get rid of `pytz` dependency as it's not installed on our servers.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, the answer to the fundamental problem here is that the pytz installation process didn't actually extract the ".egg" file (at least, this is what I noticed with a very similar issue.)

You may consider going into the site-packages folder and extracting it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It is important if you are using python v2 or python v3 - it has separate easy_install package!
In debian there are:
python-pip
python3-pip

and then 
easy_install
easy_install3

If you use wrong version of easy_install you will be updating wrong libraries.