# trouble importing pytz module after upgrade

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I recently upgraded from using Python 2.7.6 to 2.7.12. In my 2.7.6 code (that was working) I had the following import:

```
from pytz import timezone
def get_curr_time():
  pst = timezone('US/Pacific')
  cur_time = datetime.now(pst)
  return cur_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S')
```

On 2.7.12 it straightaway gives an error saying pytz no such module.

```
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

I changed `pytz` to `time` but it didn't work (I think the function `get_curr_time()` broke). Any way around this, if possible keeping the `get_curr_time()` as is?

Answer (score 1):

`pytz` is currently not installed on your machine. You need to firstly install it. To install it via. `pip`, you may simply do:

```
sudo pip install pytz
```

Comment: Are you running your code in any virtual environment? OR, you are installing `pythz` in any/other virtual environment?

Comment: Are you having multiple `pip` version on you machine? Make sure the python version you are using and the `pip` you used to install `pytz` are of same version. Another issue might be as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14970445/2063361)

Comment: I solved my issue by uninstalling pytz and reinstalling pytz (thanks for the answer, it helped point me in the right direction)

Answer (score 1):

weirdly, i was having same issue.

i did

```
pip uninstall pytz
```

then did

```
pip install pytz
```

and that worked